# SQLI prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I have amended my code and hope this is a bit more how it should be and thank you all for your help, it is much appreciated

```
    <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "project");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ? BETWEEN ? AND ?")){



$stmt->bind_param('iii',$weight, $weight1 ,$weight2);

$weight = "weight";
$weight1 = "weight + 1";
$weight2 = "weight - 1";

$stmt->execute();

echo "{$weight}";
echo "{$weight1}";
echo "{$weight2}";

$stmt->close();
}
else {

printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
?>
```

Comment: you are using 2 '?' in your prepare statement. Which means that you have to use 2 variables in `bind_param()`

Comment: Sidenote: This line `if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT....` is missing a closing `)`

Comment: Further to @Fred's note, please only present code here that you've tried - if it would result in a parse error, that needs to be fixed first `:)`.

Comment: I hope your issue is fixed after all the commenting etc

Comment: it still doesn't make too much sense. I think the only option for you is to post **raw SQL query** which you want to run using prepared statements.

Comment: Please, post raw SQL. If you have no idea what SQL query you want to run  then you have to ask another question prior this one, regarding this SQL query. But without SQL it would be impossible to answer

Comment: Yes this basically echoes the string weight weight+1 weight-1 which is useless data, what i want is the query to output users details i.e. name and age from the user table who's weight, is in a range of +1 and -1 and including the weight the user entered, but the basic query is for the weight, then i will just echo name and age with the query result...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do yourself a favor, and DON'T learn mysqli prepared statements, but consider PDO prepared statements instead.

Next, with either method you choose, you have care of error reporting first.

Next, with either method you choose, you have to count your placeholders. They **have** to match number of variables bound. In your code they aren't.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "project");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE weight BETWEEN ? AND ?");

$stmt->bind_param('ii', $from, $to);
$from = -1;
$to = 1;
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
var_dump($res->fetch_assoc());
```

something like this. But you need to make your mind with your logic first.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to assign the variable before you are binding it ? like the following

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "project");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$weight = ???;
$betweenOne = ???;
$betweenTwo = ???;

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ? BETWEEN ? AND ?")) {

    $stmt->bind_param('iii', $weight, $betweenOne, $betweenTwo);

    $stmt->execute();

    echo $weight;

    $stmt->close();
} else {
    printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```

Noticed that you are not passing the between values either so I have added them in

Fixed the closing ) thanks for the commenter :)

Take a look at the examples in the doc http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: weight contains numeric, change the 'ss' to 'ii'

Comment: Sidenote: This line `if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT....` is missing a closing `)` --- Same as what OP has. Notice SO's syntax highlighting?

Comment: Another thing `echo $weight";` remove the `"`

Comment: @OliverBS your missing a double quote on `echo $weight` either remove that double quote of add one more

Comment: No, no double quote @Tabby

Comment: @Fred-ii- agreed that double quote will make php work more, for no reason.